# Memoization sum path array

Tags: algorithm, path, sum, memoization

The problem I have,  I managed to solve recursively, but I wish for a more optimal solution that would use memoization, but I am not skilled enough to know how it should work in this context.

The problem:

There is an 2d array with random positive integers, and you are given a random amount of moves. You start moving from the top left corner, and the only moves you are allowed to make are:
left
right
down

You need to end at the bottom row and collect as much as you can on your way. You cannot revisit a position.

Memoization is about storing values and building the future results on this, but since there are so many paths one can take, how do I use it? Is it even memoization that I should use or have I made a wrong guess :) ?

Comment: @Radu: tag [algorithm] implies that the exact language doesn't matter for OP, as long as the algorithm is described.

Comment: What is it that doesn't make sense? :)

Comment: Also see [question #12712575](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712575/an-interesting-algorithm-need-pseudocode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a dynamic programming problem.  You don't really have to consider all the possible paths at each step since the details of the paths don't affect future decisions.  For each cell, you need to know the maximum amount that can be collected if you go a particular direction and taking a particular number of moves.  Nothing else affects your decisions.

```
def bestAmount(x,y,direction,n_moves):
  # If this position is off the grid, then this isn't a valid state
  if x<0 or x>=width or y>=height:
    return None
  if n_moves==0:
    # We came to the last move.
    if y!=height-1:
      # If we're not at the bottom row then this isn't a valid path.
      return None
    # Otherwise, the final cell value is part of our total.
    return cellValue(x,y)
  if direction=='down':
    # If we came down to get to this position, then the next move
    # can be either  left, right, or down
    left = bestAmount(x-1,y,'left',n_moves-1)
    right = bestAmount(x+1,y,'right',n_moves-1)
    down = bestAmount(x,y+1,'down',n_moves-1)
    return max(left,right,down)+cellValue(x,y)
  if direction=='left':
    # If we moved left to get to this position, then
    # we can't go right, since we would be visiting the same position again.
    left = bestAmount(x-1,y,'left',n_moves-1)
    down = bestAmount(x,y+1,'down',n_moves-1)
    return max(left,down)+cellValue(x,y)
  if direction=='right':
    # same logic as for left, but opposite.
    right = bestAmount(x+1,y,'right',n_moves-1)
    down = bestAmount(x,y+1,'down',n_moves-1)
    return max(right,down)+cellValue(x,y)

def solve(n_moves):
  # Start by pretending we entered the starting cell by going down
  return bestAmount(0,0,'down',n_moves)
```

If bestAmount is memoized, then you get a fairly efficient solution since the number of possibilities is relatively limited.

Treating it as a dynamic programming problem will get you an even more efficient solution though.

Comment: @user1577191: actually, working from the beginning is even better

Answer (score -1):

I guess the description of problem is something wrong. The start point is top left corner,and the only moves allowed to make are:right down. If this, memoization can also be made, you can use 0 representing right,1 representing down, then every path can be represented by a binary string, and then you can use an array dp[int(string)] to memorize the value.